# keyboard interrupt handler fire only once

Tags: assembly, keyboard, handler, interrupt

I replace 0x09 interrupt with custom interrupt

like below

The problem is that the int fire only once.

Even if I press key many many times, it fires only one time.

I tested on Virtualbox.

```
org 0x7c00

jmp start

handler:
jmp handler_code
cur_x:
db 0
handler_code:   
    mov bh,0
    mov dh, 5
    mov dl, [cur_x]
    mov ah, 2
    int 0x10

    mov al, 'A'
    mov cx, 1
    mov bh, 0
    mov ah, 0x0a
    int 0x10
    add byte [cur_x], 1

    iret

start:
push cs
pop ds

push 0
pop es
mov bx, 36

mov word [es:bx], handler
mov word [es:bx+2], cs

jmp $

times 510 - ($-$$) db 0
db 0x55
db 0xaa

times 1474560 - ($-$$) db 0
```

the code loaded on 0x7c00.
skip to the start part.
the start part has interrupt replacing routine.
it jmp to current address so it loops forever.
even if it is do-nothing eternal loop, I can fire the handler by pressing a key.
when I pressed a key, it fires. but next time, nothing happened.

the weird thing is that 
when I put the following code above jmp $, the interrupt fires 5 times.
so it seems interrupt itself is not wrong.

```
int 9
int 9
int 9
int 9
int 9
```

Comment: Just a side note: I'd be careful using `cs` in your code as given to you. Because you explicitly use `org 0x7c00`, you should set `cs` to zero before doing anything else. While it isn't a problem for your particular setup, it could be a problem for other setups (i.e. different virtual machines).

Also, perhaps the problem is that the original `int 9` routine does something that you don't, i.e. acknowledging the key press.

Comment: Where do you acknowledge the interrupt?

Comment: will you rephrase 'acknowledge the interrupt'? I don't understand.

Comment: do you mean mov 20h, al;al =20h ? I didn't put that code. do I need it? I don't know why it require that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was solved.
Thanks for the comments.

```
handler:
jmp handler_code
cur_x:
db 0
handler_code:
    mov bh,0
    mov dh, 5
    mov dl, [cur_x]
    mov ah, 2
    int 0x10


    mov al, 'A'
    mov cx, 1
    mov bh, 0
    mov ah, 0x0a
    int 0x10
    add byte [cur_x], 1

    push ax
    in al, 0x60

    mov al, 0x20
    out 0x20, al
    pop ax
    iret
```

the problem was interrupt acknowledgement.
I added

```
push ax
in al, 0x60
mov al, 0x20
out 0x20, al
pop ax
```

and it fires as expected.

thanks!